# How to add_custom_target that depends on "make install"

Tags: cmake

I'd like to add a custom target named "package" which depends on install target.
When I run `make package` it should cause first running `make install` and after that, running my custom command to create a package.

I have tried the following `DEPENDS install` but it does not work.

I get error message: No rule to make target `CMakeFiles/install.dir/all`, needed by `CMakeFiles/package.dir/all`

```
install(FILES
        "module/module.pexe"
        "module/module.nmf"
        DESTINATION "./extension")

add_custom_target(package
    COMMAND "chromium-browser" "--pack-extension=./extension"
    DEPENDS install)
```

**EDIT:** I tried `DEPENDS install` keyword and `add_dependencies(package install)` but neither of them works.

According to http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8438
it is not possible to add dependencies to built-in targets like `install` or `test`

Comment: Have you defined **install** target in current CMake project?

Comment: Now I edited the question and added the lines related to install, that I had in my CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Hmmm. I'm trying to do the exact same thing in 2017. No change that I can see.

Answer (score 9):

You can create custom target which will run install and some other script after.

### CMake script

For instance if you have a CMake script `MyScript.cmake`:

```
add_custom_target(
    MyInstall
    COMMAND
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target install
    COMMAND
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyScript.cmake"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

You can run it by building target `MyInstall`:

```
cmake --build /path/to/build/directory --target MyInstall
```

### Python script

Of course you can use any scripting language. Just remember to be polite to other platforms
(so probably it's a bad idea to write bash script, it will not work on windows).

For example python script `MyScript.py`:

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3.2 REQUIRED)

add_custom_target(
    MyInstall
    COMMAND
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target install
    COMMAND
    "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/MyScript.py"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to `install` a script which runs the custom target:

```
add_custom_target(
custom_target
[...]
)

install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND make custom_target)")
```

Refs:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/execute_process.html

---

> EDIT: I tried DEPENDS install keyword and add_dependencies(package install) but neither of them works.

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) of `add_dependencies` mentions that: `[...](but not targets generated by CMake like install)[...]`

Comment: This isn't portable, some users may be on MSVC, or have ninja installed but not make. Surely this could be done via CMAKE_COMMAND and not hard coding the build-system directly into the command.