# Is there a way to have a custom target depend on CPack?

Tags: cmake, cpack

Suppose I use CPack:

include(CPack)

This supposedly adds two extra targets: `package` and `package_source`, however if I want to make a post-package target that depends on it like this:

```
add_custom_target(do_something_to_package ...)
add_dependencies(do_something_to_package package)
```

I get an error when building, something like this:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `CMakeFiles/package.dir/all', needed by `CMakeFiles/do_something_to_package.dir/all'.  Stop.
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: There seems to be [a bug report for this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/8438).

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes following the [How to add_custom_target that depends on "make install" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163778/how-to-add-custom-target-that-depends-on-make-install), this seems to work:

```
add_custom_target(package_target
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build . --target package
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
    COMMENT "Building package"
    DEPENDS stuff_required_for_package
    VERBATIM
)
```

Not exactly elegant, but it could be worse! Also it doesn't seem to play particularly nicely with parallel builds. Not exactly sure why but for release I'd do a non-parallel build just to be safe.